# Postgres don't allow my application to connect

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, properties-file

I have a database server, where I can log in from my machine using `psql`:

```
root@engine:/devops# psql -h database -U postgres -d uat
```

Given the follow result :

```
psql (9.5.0, server 9.4.5)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

uat=#
```

But if I try to connect from my application:

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host *** user "postgres", database "uat", SSL off
```

This is my `props.properties` used by my application:

```
uatDb.user=postgres
uatDb.password=***
uatDb.driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
uatDb.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/uat?ssl=true
uatDb.port=5432
uatDb.name=uat
uatDb.host=database
```

I even imported the public certificate from my database provider into my application trustore, but doesn't seems to work either.

I wonder why I can connect via `psql` but my application don't.
Any help ?

Comment: As it says, no [pg_hba.conf entry](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: But if that's the case, why can I log in using `psql` but not my application ?

Comment: `psql` is using SSL, your application is not. The `pg_hba` rule also refers to the client's IP address, though you haven't mentioned whether these connections are coming from the same machine.

Comment: Oops... Noticed you've got `ssl=true` in your connection string. Doesn't look like it's taking effect, though I have no idea why...

Comment: Yep, that's exactly my point @NickBarnes. Even using `ssl=true` on my `url`, it doesn't seems to have any effect tough.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/ssl-client.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did @NickBarnes. I have asked for the public certificate from my database provider to import into my trustore, but even that didn't work. :(

Comment: Java blocks all self-signed certificates by default, even if you import the server cert. You have to use the NonValidatingFactory class as per Eric Bravick's answer below. The pg_hba.conf error message is misleading. It's not that there is no appropriate pg_hba.conf entry; it's that the pg_hba.conf entry doesn't allow you in because your Java client wasn't using SSL, since Java rejects self-signed certs by default.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the connections are coming in with SSL off, this is most likely due to the certificate validation restriction.  Could you try adding:

sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

and see if this resolves the issue?

Comment: More specifically, appended as: &sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory to ssl=true